# Where does pytest maintain all the fixtures currently in scope?

Tags: pytest

When we instantiate some object instance in a pytest fixture and yield it back to the test session where exactly is it kept within pytest internals for the fixture injection magic to take place? I'd like a bit more conceptual meat to back my understanding of things, maybe even some concrete implementation details. Do all our fixtures get registered in some giant dictionary? Where do the fixtures go exactly?

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell there is in fact a dict which backs all the fixtures currently in scope for a given test session.

Starting off with this [github search](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Apytest-dev%2Fpytest+path%3A%2F%5Esrc%5C%2F%2F+++%5C%22fixture%5C%22&type=code) for this query `repo:pytest-dev/pytest path:/^src\//   \"fixture\"` I immediately came upon this hit in the top level init module.

## `__init__.py`

```py
from _pytest.fixtures import fixture # <----------- immediately caught my eye
from _pytest.fixtures import FixtureDef
from _pytest.fixtures import FixtureLookupError
from _pytest.fixtures import FixtureRequest
from _pytest.fixtures import yield_fixture
```

https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/556e075d23a91eb42821129a5d874ec3174e17ad/src/pytest/__init__.py#L22-L26

and a little further down in the same [module](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/556e075d23a91eb42821129a5d874ec3174e17ad/src/pytest/__init__.py#L105-L108).

```py
__all__ = [
    …
    "fixture", # <----------- took note of this guy in particular
    "FixtureDef",
    "FixtureLookupError",
    "FixtureRequest”,
]
```

## `fixtures.py`

From there I immediately jumped to the `fixtures.py` source which presented this very strong clue exposing the FixtureManager class which you can immediately begin to imagine somehow maintaining all the instances in memory.

```py
def pytest_sessionstart(session: "Session") -> None:
    session._fixturemanager = FixtureManager(session)
```

https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/556e075d23a91eb42821129a5d874ec3174e17ad/src/_pytest/fixtures.py#L110-L111

### FixtureManager

And lo and behold the manager maintains the fixture definitions/instances, very good.

```py
class FixtureManager:
    """pytest fixture definitions and information is stored and managed
    from this class.
    ...
    Upon the test-setup phases all fixturenames are instantiated, retrieved
    by a lookup of their FuncFixtureInfo.
```

https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/556e075d23a91eb42821129a5d874ec3174e17ad/src/_pytest/fixtures.py#L1356-L1358

very curious, this FuncFixtureInfo, also defined in that module, is like metadata stuff associated with the objects our fixtures wrap.

And finally checking out the manager's init for its member data we see the internals for where our fixtures live.

```py
    def __init__(self, session: "Session") -> None:
        ...
        # Maps a fixture name (argname) to all of the FixtureDefs in the test
        # suite/plugins defined with this name. Populated by parsefactories().
        # TODO: The order of the FixtureDefs list of each arg is significant,
        #       explain.
        self._arg2fixturedefs: Final[Dict[str, List[FixtureDef[Any]]]] = {} # <---- the DICT!! It is a dict after all
        self._holderobjseen: Final[Set[object]] = set()
```

https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/556e075d23a91eb42821129a5d874ec3174e17ad/src/_pytest/fixtures.py#L1393-L1398
https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/556e075d23a91eb42821129a5d874ec3174e17ad/src/_pytest/fixtures.py#L1397

### FixtureDefinition

Going one layer deeper to the values of the `_arg2fixturedefs` dict we find the `FixtureDefinition` class which at the bottom maintains a reference to the actual fixture value down in `self.cached_result`

```py
class FixtureDef(Generic[FixtureValue]):
    """A container for a fixture definition.

    Note: At this time, only explicitly documented fields and methods are
    considered public stable API.
    """
    def __init__(
        self,
        fixturemanager: "FixtureManager",
        baseid: Optional[str],
        argname: str,
        func: "_FixtureFunc[FixtureValue]",
        scope: Union[Scope, _ScopeName, Callable[[str, Config], _ScopeName], None],
        params: Optional[Sequence[object]],
        unittest: bool = False,
        ids: Optional[
            Union[Tuple[Optional[object], ...], Callable[[Any], Optional[object]]]
        ] = None,
        *,
        _ispytest: bool = False,
    ) -> None:
        ...
        # If the fixture was executed, the current value of the fixture.
        # Can change if the fixture is executed with different parameters.
        self.cached_result: Optional[_FixtureCachedResult[FixtureValue]] = None
```

https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/556e075d23a91eb42821129a5d874ec3174e17ad/src/_pytest/fixtures.py#L913-L981

---

All this analysis was conducted on the main branch for the pytest github repo https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/commits/main examined at commit 556e075d23a91eb42821129a5d874ec3174e17ad